# Local Xenial Repo (debmirror) doesn't allow apt-get update Ign

Tags: 16.04, apt, mirrors, localrepository

{{NOTE: I have tried every solution in this forum. I've searched. I know some will say this is a duplicate, which it is, but I couldn't add to the other post}}

I have a local repo of Xenial (32 and 64bit).  I use debmirror and everything looks great. However when I point to my local repo and run apt-get update, I get:

Ign: 5 http://10.x.x.x/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign: 6 http://10.x.x.x/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
.......etc

Client can't find any packages, which I know are in the repo.

I've tried many solutions I found in this forum (removing 50appstream file, etc..), but none fix the issue.

It does "Get" Release files, but Packages is Ign.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have a similar problem.